# is there any single library for twitter sharing in ios4 and ios 5

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, twitter

I need to share one video url getting from my server in twitter.

And my app must be compatible for both ios 4.0 and ios 5.0.
I know that there is twitter+oauth library for ios 4.0 and twitter inbuilt library for ios 5.0. And my functionality is twitter library  need to ask user credentials only once for twitter authentication and need to post that video url in background with out asking user permission.

From the second time onwards video must posted in background.

As per my knowledge we have different libraries we need to use but is there any solution that do implemant my task with one library.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a beautiful implementation, check out [DETweetComposeViewController](http://i0sdev.tumblr.com/post/14504185908/detweetcomposeviewcontroller).

It will provide you with a UI that looks almost identical to what iOS5 users now are growing accustomed to. The great point is, it works on iOS4 and iOS5 flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....But in the link you provided missing OAuthConsumerCredentials.So i can't able to run this.

Comment: You did not follow the instructions on the GIThub-project-overview - read them carefully.

Answer (score 1):

GetShareKit was a basic library created by Nate Weiner that's now outdated. If you check it's [`GitHub`](https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit) source, the last commit was sometime in 2010. This version is buggy and has about 20+ compile warnings. this uses an older version of the Facebook and Twitter sharing mechanisms that are now deprecated and also, buggy. Clicking Twitter's "Share", for eg, won't dismiss the sharing dialog.

So, a bunch of developers forked off the original library and now maintain what's called [ShareKit 2.0 SDK](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit). If you check the wiki, you'll learn that all new services like Foursquare, LinkedIn, InstaPaper, EverNote have been added to this new version. Happy Coding!

Comment: What happens? I successfully have deployed it on iOS 5.

Comment: most of the cases  twitter is not posting messages from sharekit 2.0 in my end

Comment: Most of the cases? Well, that means it works "in some cases" on ios 5 - so how can you say it doesn't work on iOS 5? The issue could be something else, did you try debugging? We have pointed you in the right direction in terms of your original question which was to find a library. Now for the specifics, you would have to do some  research online by yourself buddy :)