# Twitter for Ios 4,5 and 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can anyone let me know how to use the twitter framework in my app for ios 4,5 and 6 ?

Comment: Please research thoroughly ....

Comment: This is unclear. "How to use"; use for what, sending tweets, adding contact information from twitter, getting users' uploaded pictures? You should show code that you've already tried, and ask about specific errors you having with it. (Plus, using Twitter in an iOS app is a common task, there are plenty of guides and documentation about.)

Comment: "Can anyone let me know how to use the twitter framework in my app for ios 4,5 and 6 ?" - Sure. Read the docs. Write some code. Come back when you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet for creating and presenting the `TWTweetComposeViewController` using the buit-in-twitter frame work included in the iOS 5:

Include the twitter frame work and import `#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>`

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = 
        [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Initial Tweet Text!"];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
}
```

This is a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5) for you.

Comment: i made one application for ios4. in that app i use the SA_OauthTwitter class now i make this applicaton for ios 6 how to i use twitter?

Comment: you need to set target to 4.3 or else and compile, then check whether it works on iOS 4, i didn't checked it on iOS 4 device, So I'm not sure. :)

Comment: can we use the SA_OauthTwitter Classes and twitter framework for ios 6 in one application...

Comment: @VirjaRahul: twitter framework will work with iOS 4, check these links for clarification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132745/is-there-any-single-library-for-twitter-sharing-in-ios4-and-ios-5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474153/twitter-integration-in-ios-4-5-app

Comment: @VirjaRahul: you can use twitter framework for iOS 4,5 and 6 :)

Comment: @VirjaRahul "Can we use this, can we use that" - GOOGLE IT